# visual studio web service response return nothing

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, soap

I am trying to call a webservice from visual studio (vb 2013). I tried to call the webservice from SOAP UI and it is returning the response correctly. I added a web reference to the vb code and tried to call the webservice by doing the below:

```
    Dim s As New localhost.protoService
        Dim ws_req As New localhost.newUserRequest

        Dim ws_response As New localhost.newUserResponse

        ws_req.fullName = TextBox1.Text

        ws_response = s.newUser(ws_req)
```

the ws_response is always returning nothing, though the webservice at the server side has completed successfully. I validated the namespaces in the reference code and all seems OK, any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that the namespace should be empty in the response, when I set [Namespace]:="" it worked fine, I hope it will help whoever faced this problem.